# In C#, are Lambda Expressions objects?

Tags: c#, lambda

In C#, are lambda expressions objects? If so, what sort of object are they?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Lambda expressions themselves only exist in source code. They don't have a type themselves, which is why the compiler always insists they're convert to a specific type.

That's why this code doesn't compile:

```
// No idea what type to convert to!
object x = y => y.Length;
```

But this does:

```
Func<string, int> x = y => y.Length;
```

Lambda expressions are always converted to *either* a delegate type *or* an expression tree type. Similarly, anonymous methods are always converted to a delegate type.

Comment: +1 Nice answer.  I like that you explain how lambda expressions are really just syntax sugar for either a delegate or an expression tree.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, lambda expressions are converted to either a [`delegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx) or an [expression tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx) - both of which are objects.

Answer (score 4):

Lambda operations in Linq build what are called expression trees. You can read a bit about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics.aspx).

Comment: Well they might. Or they might build delegates. It depends on the provider.

Answer (score 0):

It's an anonymous function that has to conform to some kind of delegate.
[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)
So, in fact, they're instances of some delegate type.